# HTML Get Input Value

Tags: html, input

I am trying to make a link, and place a variable in the URL like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="index.html?color=">Main Page</a>
  <input type="color" id="colorPicker" value="#808080">
</body>
<html>
```

I am trying to send the user to `index.html?color=VALUE GOES HERE`. Instead of `VALUE GOES HERE`, I would like the current color input value.

Comment: you want to navigate the user to url when he click submit for example ?

Comment: Oh, you mean forms? Why don't you use the `<form>` tag?

Comment: @Microsmsm No, I just want the user to go when the click the Main Page link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way that I can think to do this is with JavaScript, so sorry if this is not what you are looking for:

```js
function urlUpdate(hex) {
  document.getElementById("link").href = "index.html?color=" + hex;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <a id='link' href="index.html?color=">Main Page</a>
  <input type="color" id="colorPicker" value="#808080" onchange="urlUpdate(value)">
</body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 2):

**You may use forms** ,

> The method attribute specifies how to send form-data (the form-data is
>   sent to the page specified in the action attribute).
>
> The form-data can be sent as URL variables (with method="get")

```html
<form action="index.html" method="get">
  <input type="color" name="color" value="#808080">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I am just looking for the user to go to the home page if they click on the link, is there a easy way for this to do that?